# How to change font family using adf

Tags: css, fonts, oracle-adf, webfonts, skin

i use this for invoke news fonts to my page, but not result. Why?
This fonts don't exist for default. I did download and insert in a folder Font in my skin.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'akzidenzgroteskregular';
    src: url('Font/Akzidenz-Grotesk (R) Extended Regular.ttf') format('truetype');

    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'klavikaRegular';
    src: url('Font/klavika-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');


    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'KlavikaBold';
    src: url('Font/klavika-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');


    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: How do you load your CSS? I use the same kind of code but I had to load the CSS as a regular CSS with af:resource in my page template.

Comment: Sydney, i create a skin for my project. For resolv my problem i use this:

@font-face {
    font-family: "akzidenzgrotesk-medium-webfont";
    src: url("Font/akzidenzgrotesk-medium-webfont.eot");
    src: url("Font/akzidenzgrotesk-medium-webfont.woff")format("woff"),
         url("Font/akzidenzgrotesk-medium-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("Font/akzidenzgrotesk-medium-webfont.svg#akzidenzgrotesk-medium-webfont") format("svg");
      
    font-style: normal;
}

After, in font family for my component i use the same font name: akzidenzgrotesk-medium-webfont.

Answer (score 1):

I used this in some projects:

```css
.AFDefaultFont:alias,
body
{
 font-family: Comic Sans, Tahoma, sans-serif !important;
 font-size: 14px !important;
}
```

Comment: I use some choice similar:

@font-face {
    font-family: "akzidenzgrotesk-medium-webfont";
    src: url("Font/akzidenzgrotesk-medium-webfont.eot");
    src: url("Font/akzidenzgrotesk-medium-webfont.woff")format("woff"),
         url("Font/akzidenzgrotesk-medium-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("Font/akzidenzgrotesk-medium-webfont.svg#akzidenzgrotesk-medium-webfont") format("svg");
      
    font-style: normal;
}

Comment: No you didn't. You don't override the default fonts provided by ADF. Use at least .AFDefaultFont:alias.

Comment: not use it because the font is not equal for all. For text in a input text is one, for header tables is other and so on.

Comment: Then you need to use different selectors (ex: af|inputText::content{}) for every component. Read more here: http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/skin-selectors.html